# How to disable width for carousel control buttons in React-Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, react-bootstrap

I've been trying to alter the width of the carousel next and prev buttons so that they don't overlap with the images or links I have inside the carousel, but the method that works in bootstrap:

```css
.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

doesn't seem to work in the React-Bootstrap Carousel component.

Whenever I change it in the browser from:

```
.carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next {
    width: 15%;
}
```

to:

```
.carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next {
    width: 5%;
}
```

it works perfectly. But when I make this change in my CSS file it doesn't work.

Is there another way to make this change that will work in the Bootstrap-React carousel component? Or am I doing something wrong, like using the wrong className?

Just to clarify, I'm trying to change the width or size of the button as a whole, not just the button icon.

[screenshot of button width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnLc0.png)

In this picture, the black box is the current width of the button. Clicking anywhere inside this area will cause you to go to the next slide. I would like to change that to the size of the red box so that the button isn't overlapping at all with the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

Create the custom CSS file and add your required CSS to it.

Then import that file in your component.(Ex : import './custom.css')

(Note : Use the carousel-control-prev, carousel-constrol-next as class name)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm actually trying to change the width of the entire button area, not just the icon width. I've edited the original question to clarify exactly what I mean. I've also tried changing the icon padding and margins, but that doesn't either.